# PF / IceFloor - Redirecting a service / port to a specific IP

Tags: network, firewall

What I'm trying to do is redirect all requests to a certain service or port to a specific IP address with [IceFloor](http://www.hanynet.com/icefloor/) as the frontend for PF.
In the example I'm posting en1 is my only enabled network adapter, 192.168.0.1 is the server I'm trying to redirect to and port 53 is the port I want to redirect all traffic for to that IP.

Icefloor has been letting me enter (but not completely add to the ruleset) these two lines through the custom rules page. 
I don't get a bad syntax warning as though I've put in a bad rule, but the rules aren't appearing in either the icefloor custom rules GUI list or the icefloor.custom_rules file.

```
rdr on en1 inet proto tcp from any to any port 53 -> 192.168.0.1 port 53
rdr on en1 inet proto udp from any to any port 53 -> 192.168.0.1 port 53
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, or if this is even possible?

Additional info:

- OS X 10.11.1
- I'm not running a DNS server on EN1
- I am running a DNS server on 192.168.0.1
- EN1 and 192.168.0.1 are on the same host, 192.168.0.1 is on a virtual adapter belonging to an OpenVPN TUN.
- The purpose is to redirect DNS requests to any IP address to the DNS server I'm running.
- EN1 is on 192.168.16.0/24
- EN0 is a disabled adapter configured to use DHCP when active

Comment: Hope that helps,
If there's anything else I can let you know please ask :)